# Can I configure an event trigger to stop sending updates to the destination during specific hours of a day in ADF?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF event-based trigger that sends the update to the destination. The destination cannot accept the updates during its maintenance hours. Is there a way to stop processing the updates and continue back once the destination is back running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no timeframe for event base triggers, so you cannot limit them for firing.

You can add an activity to the pipeline to check the time, and stop the pipeline if its on maintenance hours.

Please note that the event will not fire again (for this event) after maintenance hours are over, so you will need to create a mechanism to complete the missing updates.